# refactoring python function that uses pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I got in my code 20+ of and will certainly have more occurrences of the following snippet where I have almost always the same pattern of code, which in essence is (number corresponds to comments in snippet below):

1. calculate a test which depends on several columns of the df, the test could multiply, divide, add, any operations on any columns, and replace inf by nan
2. get a mask of all non nan
3. create a valid df using the mask
4. create a new column adding '_mod' to the original column considered and filling it by something
5. filling the rest of the values on the '_mod' column with another formula that like in step 1 can be any operation on any columns, using the valid df previously created in 3

### Snippet

```
# col1
logger.info('col1')
# 1
col1_test = (df["colX"] / df["colZ"] / df["colY"] / df["colX"]).replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan)
# 2
col1_mask = (~pd.isna(col1_test))
# 3
col1_valid = df[col1_mask]
# 4
df['col1_mod'] = np.nan
# 5
df.loc[col1_mask, 'col1_mod'] = (col1_valid["colX"] - col1_valid["colZ"]) / col1_valid[
    "colY"]

# col2
logger.info('col2')
col2_test = (df["colA"] / df["colY"] / df["colA"]).replace(
    [np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan)
col2_mask = (~pd.isna(col2_test))
col2_valid = df[col2_mask]
df['col2_mod'] = 0.0
df.loc[col2_mask, 'col2_mod'] = col2_valid["colA"] / col2_valid["colY"]
```

What I wrote so far to refactor is the following.
But I guess it could be taken a step further, I'm blocked in particular by the commented (`# df.loc[mask, f'{oldcol}_mod'] = ...`) which could solve the whole thing if the function returned the df itself. Yet I fail to see how to pass a list of operations as a parameter to the refactored function that uses somehting (`valid`) created whithin the refactored function itself.

```
def refactored(df, oldcol, dftest, replace):
    logger.info(oldcol)
    test = dftest.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan)
    mask = (~pd.isna(test))
    valid = df[mask]
    df[f'{oldcol}_mod'] = replace
    # df.loc[mask, f'{oldcol}_mod'] = ...
    return valid, mask


col1_valid, col1_mask = refactored(df, 'col1', df["colX"] / df["colZ"] / df["colY"] / df["colX"], np.nan)
df.loc[col1_mask, 'col1_mod'] = (col1_valid["colX"] - col1_valid["colZ"]) / col1_valid["colY"]
col2_valid, col2_mask = refactored(df, 'col2',df["colA"] / df["colY"] / df["colA"] , 0.0)
df.loc[col2_mask, 'col2_mod'] = col2_valid["colA"] / col2_valid["colY"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using [`pd.DataFrame.eval`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.eval.html) with [`pd.DataFrame.pipe`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pipe.html):

```
def refactored(df, oldcol, dftest, replace, mod_col, series_col):
    # ...some logic...
    test = df.eval(dftest).replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan)
    # ... some more logic...
    df.loc[mask, mod_col] = df.eval(series_col)
    return df

df = df.pipe(refactored, 'col1', 'colX / colZ / colY / colX', np.nan,
             'col1_mod', '(colX - colZ) / colY')\
       .pipe(refactored, 'col2', 'colA / colY / colA', 0.0,
             'col2_mod', 'colA / colY')
```

In general, you should never need to pass *series* as function arguments.

Comment: that works perfect, til pipe and eval I never used before. However, why you say > you should never need to pass series as function arguments, in that case could I achieve what I want without all that i.e having a new col being the result of iferror(eval1), replace, eval2 ?

Comment: @euri10, All I meant was you can pass strings instead of series, as in my solution. It's a lot cleaner and `eval` should also be more efficient.